# Assembly code doesn't print string

Tags: string, assembly, x86

So basically I'm trying to write a hello world program in assembly. The program exits as it should but no string is printed along the way. There are no errors anywhere either. I suspect that I am declaring or using the string wrong somehow.

```
    .intel_syntax noprefix

.data

msg:
    .ascii "Hello World"

.text

.globl _start

_start:
    mov eax, 4 #call write
    mov ebx, 1 #output into stdout
    mov ecx, msg #what to write
    mov edx, 11 #length of what to write
    int 0x80

    mov eax, 1 #exit
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

I have also tried replacing

```
mov ecx, msg
```

with

```
mov ecx, [msg]
```

but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: What assembler are you using?

Comment: To be honest I'm unsure what an assembler actually is but to create the binary i use the commands "as -o HelloWorld.o HelloWorld.s" and "ld -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.o"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `mov ecx, offset msg` or `lea ecx, msg`.
Also make sure you are assembling as 32 bit code in case you are on a 64 bit system.